# pcap.net .exe error with dll

Tags: .net, dll, pcap.net

I have a program using pcap.net. It works well when I am launching it from the developer, but fails completely when I use the exe. Here's what I've done and the exception:

1. Add existing item to project (PcapDotNet.base.dll, .core.dll, .core.extensions.dll, and .packets.dll)
2. Gone to references and added to their location in my project's folder. No yellow warning triangles
3. Gone to Build->project->compile to make sure the configuration says "release"
4. Gone to Build->proejct->compile to make sure the target cpu says "x86".

[image]

What did I do wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For those in the future that is wondering why PCAP is having issues:

It's because those computers the .exe was used on didn't have WinPCap on it. Since Pcap.net is a wrapper on top of that. However, I still had to have the pcap dll within the same folder as the .exe for it to run sucessfully.

Comment: Yes, quoting the Pcap.Net user guide: "Install WinPcap 4.1.2". https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20Pcap.Net%20in%20your%20programs&referringTitle=Pcap.Net%20User%20Guide

Comment: Just want to note, I pay have WinPCap installed, but it still will fail unless I have the .exe in the same folder as a copy of pcapdonet.core.dll

Comment: What exe are you referring to? If you mean the exe that you run, that of course it has to find the DLL in order to run.